# How to create a hyperlink to a placemark on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, bookmarks

The URL http://members.startupguild.net/#andrewdavey takes me to a Google Map and displays a placemark.

Please can you tell me how to code this (or point me at some instructions). I have looked on these sites but can't see an answer:

- http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is URL-encode some sort of an identifier for each of the overlays. In the example you show, #andrewdavey is that identifier. When the page loads, the javascript parses the identifier from the URL, and requests the corresponding marker/location with that ID, at which to open the info window.

A simple example would be something like:

```
var myLocations = new Array();
myLocations["#id1"] = new GLatLng(45,45);
myLocations["#id2"] = new GLatLng(15,35);
.
.
.
```

Then you'd look up the key: #id1, #id2, ... etc from the URL, and acquire the location as

```
var selectedLocation = myLocations[url_id];
```

You can then open an info window/do whatever at that location using the maps API. Note that  the location on the map does not have to come from a hard coded array - it could be looked up from a data source for instance.

Comment: This makes sense. It's a bit of a workaround though - I thought Google Maps would have this functionality built in - e.g. by calling a unique identifier on a KML. Until they do, I'll use this technique. Thanks :-)

Comment: I was assuming that you'd want to populate this from your own data source, like a database of markers/descriptions or similar. That's how I've done it in the past. You might be able to do it with KML, but I haven't looked at that.. In my application markers on the map could be added by the user, so I always had to look them up..

Comment: In any case, I always really enjoyed my maps api work, hope you do too! If you do find how to achieve this in an alternative way, it would be good to update your question with your selected approach, for the benefit of any future onlookers!

Comment: Yes I would do a lookup from my DB. I want to keep the KML file as small as possible. I'll update my post if I find a better way :-)